# Problems using "SVN: Import into repository" of Netbeans

Tags: svn, netbeans, svnkit

I got this error while I try to use the option of Netbeans "Team+Subversion+Import Into Repository" to create a repository of a Netbeans project into a local repository folder previously created (c://Repositorios/ProjectExample).

Can you help me

Regards
RS

The error message is:
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Can't create session
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///C:/Repositorios/ProjectExample'
Couldn't open a repository
Unable to open repository 'file:///C:/Repositorios/ProjectExample'
Unsupported FS format
Expected FS format between '1' and '7'; found format '8'

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans uses some plug-in that is based on SVNKit (Subversion rewritten in Java). SVNKit does not support the latest Subversion 1.10.x or 1.11.x versions and repository formats (FSFS 8 format).

Your repository was created or upgraded with Subversion 1.10.x or newer tools and you can't access this repository with SVNKit vie the local file:// protocol. You won't receive the error if you switch to HTTP(S) instead of the file:// protocol or switch from SVNKit to JavaHL (I don't remember whether it is possible in Netbeans, though).